# Application crashing when copying log file while it is running

Tags: .net, logging

I have written a small application in Visual Basic (but the problem I am describing would probably appear for any language) and I'm having a problem with my log file.

If I try to copy my application log file while the application is running (which is writing the log file the whole time), the application crashes.

It looks like the system is trying to access a file which is being used by the application.

Currently, when I want to log a message, I'm opening the file (checking first if it exists, creating it if it doesn't), then write, and finally closing the file.

This is in fact the code:

```
Public Shared Sub WriteToLog(ByVal msg As String)
        Dim logID As Integer = 0
        Dim fileName As String = Application.StartupPath & "/log.log"
        'Check the file
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(fileName) Then
            'Get ID of log entry
            Dim str As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(fileName)
            Dim array() As String = Split(str, vbCrLf)
            logID = array.Length - 1
        Else
            'Create if it does not exist
            Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
            Dim s As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fs)
            'Write header:
            s.Write("LOGID;TIME;CLASSIFICATION;INFO" & vbCrLf)
            s.Close()
            fs.Close()
            logID = 1
        End If

        'Log it
        Dim fs1 As FileStream = New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)
        Dim s1 As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fs1)
        s1.Write(logID & ";" & DateTime.Now.ToString() & ";" & msg & vbCrLf)
        s1.Close()
        fs1.Close()

    End Sub
```

My doubt is: would be preferable to leave the lof file opened all the time the application is running, or would that cause the application to crash anyway?

Comment: _"the application crashes."_ - on what line? Set a breakpoint and trigger the bug. And yes, you should keep the file open while your program is running, otherwise a lot of logging will cause a lot of delays. Or just use a logging framework like log4net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the other way around, the application is trying to access the file while another program is using it.

You need error handling in your code, so that it doesn't crash if it fails to open the file. Put a `Try...Catch` around the code in the method, and handle the exception that you catch.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Keep the log opened should be a problem. There are many tools like Textpad, which will check the file's state when the window comes up and give you a message back saying the file is altered, do you want to reload.

This issue is probably specific to the editor that you have used to open the log file.